# Checking if the empty string respects a regex in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I know that Matlab's [`regexp`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) function is the one I should use to look for a match between a string and a regular expression.

However, when an empty string does fit the regex, it shows the same result as when it does not:

```
expr1 = 'b'
regexp('a', expr1, 'match') % Returns empty cell: no match
regexp('b', expr1, 'match') % Returns cell with 'b'
regexp('', expr1, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: no match

expr2 = ''
regexp('a', expr2, 'match') % Returns empty cell: no match
regexp('', expr2, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: but it matches

expr3 = 'b?'
regexp('a', expr3, 'match') % Returns empty cell: no match
regexp('b', expr3, 'match') % Returns cell with 'b'
regexp('', expr3, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: but it matches

expr4 = '|b'
regexp('a', expr4, 'match') % Returns empty cell: no match
regexp('b', expr4, 'match') % Returns cell with 'b'
regexp('', expr4, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: but it matches

expr5 = '.*'
regexp('b', expr5, 'match') % Returns cell with 'b'
regexp('', expr5, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: but it matches
```

When the result is an empty cell, I can not differentiate between "there is no match between the string and the regex" and "the string matches, but it's just an empty-string".

**How can I distinguish between these two cases ?**

Another way to do what I want would be to have a function that tests whether a (possibly empty) string (not its substrings) matches exactly a regex, but I could not find it in Matlab.

**EDIT**: I'm working with Matlab2015a, and I did try replacing `''` with `blanks(0)`, but it gives the same results.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused here. `''` is an empty character array, there is *nothing* to match.

Comment: What about blank(0) then ? It is a string with 0 characters, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `expr2=''; regexp('', expr2, 'match')  % Returns empty cell: but it matches`: *it matches* in your brain, but there is no match to anything matching that expression, you've not asked to match against anything...

Comment: I understand now that there is nothing to match. But the empty string is in the accepted language described by `expr3-5`, isn't it ? Is there a method to know if a string -possibly with 0 characters- is in the language described by a regex ?

Comment: What do you mean by *Is there a method to know if a string -possibly with 0 characters- is in the language described by a regex ?* ?

Comment: To address some of the comments, an empty string can *technically* satisfy a regular expression. For example, `''` satisfies the expression `'b?'` because it contains "only 0 or 1 b", specifically 0. `'a'` doesn't satisfy it. If you think of it in terms of *satisfying* the expression, versus *matching* it, I think it makes a little more sense. You can technically distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you might need to do this, but there is a way for you to distinguish between your "no match" and "empty string match" conditions for every case except your fourth match expression `'|b'`. That expression appears to try and match "nothing or `'b'`", which I don't think is any different from your previous expression `'b?'`, which is "`'b'` 0 times or 1 time".

If you add [beginning and end anchors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42983) to your match expression and use the [`'emptymatch'` option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45-option) for [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), then you will get an empty cell `{}` for non-matches and a cell containing an empty string `{''}` for your empty string matches:

```
expr1 = '^b$';
regexp('a', expr1, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {}
regexp('b', expr1, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {'b'}
regexp('', expr1, 'match', 'emptymatch')    % Result = {}

expr2 = '^$';
regexp('a', expr2, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {}
regexp('', expr2, 'match', 'emptymatch')    % Result = {''}

expr3 = '^b?$';
regexp('a', expr3, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {}
regexp('b', expr3, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {'b'}
regexp('', expr3, 'match', 'emptymatch')    % Result = {''}

expr5 = '^.*$';
regexp('b', expr5, 'match', 'emptymatch')   % Result = {'b'}
regexp('', expr5, 'match', 'emptymatch')    % Result = {''}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had not found this emptymatch option !